# Why Laravel CSS (style.css) is not loading instead 'stdin' is loading css?

Tags: php, laravel-5

This is how I added css file. CSS file is in `public/css/style.css`.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('css/style.css') }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

**Disabling the *.css.map functionality at gulpfile.js** 
At last, Solved the issue. Reason behind the problem is, for each file that is compiled, a companion *.css.map file in the same directory by elixir. And the *.css.map file was redirecting the sass file in stdin file, that made the php server confused, which css to load. I stopped the file from being automatically created by putting the line in gulpfile.js before the elixir mix function.

```
elixir.config.sourcemaps = false;
```